# Java - Exporting with Eclipse Sharing Problems

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I have a java application that **I** can run when I export a Executable Jar. "I" is bold because only I can run it. When I sent it to someone else in an email it wouldn't run for them, I'd like to mention they were both macs. Also I would like to know how to set it up professionally with a .app file with a favicon and name. I have scanned through the internet and stack overflow search and found nothing to suit me. I would also lime help with the search term I am most likely missing! :-)


Thanks In Advance,
Louis



BTW the title is a bit cryptic… didn't know how to word it :-).

When I type `java -jar myprogram.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
```

Comment: Did you ask those users how they run it? By double click or what?

Comment: I just went on to the other computer and double-clicked exactly how I ran it!

Comment: Try from terminal with: `java -jar YourProgram.jar`

Comment: Also, check whether they have Java installed by typing: `java -version` in terminal.

Comment: @brano 2nd comment: on my computer or theirs, ps I would like it to be double-click
also 3rd comment: I checked and the version is exactly the same on both.

Comment: On their. And I have no idea how to solve it to be a double click. I'm not a OSX user. I'm here to answer issue about Java program itself.

Comment: @brano I put the error on the Question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception means that you have compiled your program using java 1.7 (type java -version). In order to run your program on other computer you have to have java 1.7 installed there as well.

Please see the following topic, where you can find more info how to resolve it:

[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)